# backtrack or kali linux ??? Which is best for a beginner pen tester ?

Tags: linux, penetration-test, kali-linux

I am using backtrack right now but i also wish to switch to kali linux if its more interactive. Because i am just a beginner pen tester. I tried with both bt4 and bt5, but novice in kali linux.

Comment: kali is just the new version of backtrack with some modification. Backtrack is based on Ubuntu. Use Kali-linux however as it is better supported. They have removed/replaced few tools in kali

Comment: if you are already familiar with Backtrack, they using Kali is no different nor difficult

Comment: see http://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-whats-new

Answer (score 5):

That's a nonsense question, since BackTrack and Kali are the same, just Kali a higher version.

It's like asking, Squeeze or Wheezy? Both are the stable versions of Debian but Wheezy is more updated than Squeezy, and with longer support.

Answer (score 2):

Kali is newer, more recently updated, and installs rather than being a liveCD.  Pretty much all there is to it.

Kali is best if you want to set up a machine for pentesting especially.

Neither Kali nor BT offer anything that you couldn't assemble onto your own favourite distro to be fair.

Comment: I always had a BT5 as a partition so it's possible to be installed rather than run from a CD but I guess it's a mute point either way as BT is no longer being maintained.